# Clear cache from jstree node

Tags: jstree

I want to force an ajax call every time the user opens a node i.e. no caching.   A little googling suggested deleting the children of a node after the user closes it.  Seems pretty simple but I cant get it to work.
In the code below the after_close event is in fact fired but the three statements to delete the child nodes appear to have no effect.  I conclude this because I observe the initial ajax call in fiddler when the node is first opened but closing the node and re-opening it does not generate a call.
Notes:
  I am using a random number parameter to prevent caching on the browser.
  I have set the 'check_callback' flag per [the documentation](http://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/).

```
// load the tree
        $('#tree').jstree({
            'core': {
                "themes": { "theme": "classic", "dots": false, "icons": false },
                'html_titles': true,
                'load_open': true,
                'data': {
                    'url': 'GetChildNodes/',
                    'data': function (node) {
                        return { 'id': node.id === '#' ? '0_0' : node.id, 'noCache': Math.random() };
                    }
                },
                'check_callback': function () { return true; }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "ui"]
        });

        // Handles tree view links so that the tree view does not intercept the event.
        $("#tree").delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
            if ($("#tree").jstree("is_leaf", this)) {
                document.location.href = this;
            }
            else {
                $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", this);
            }
        });

        $('#tree').on('after_close.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true);
            var children = tree.get_children_dom(data);
            tree.delete_node(children);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
    $('#tree').on('after_close.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true);
        tree.delete_node(data.node.children);
        tree._model.data[data.node.id].state.loaded = false;
    });
```